# sed is zeroing second value

Tags: kubernetes, sed

In Kubernetes in initContainer I am running following command to replace two values taken from env variables:

```
      initContainers:
      - name: init-atsconfigs
        image: busybox
        command: ['sh', '-c', 'cd /tmp/ats && for i in $(ls *.config); do cat $i > /etc/trafficserver_edit/$i; done; sed -i "s/_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_OVERRIDE_/$AWS_ACCESS_KEY/g" /etc/trafficserver_edit/*.config', 'cd /tmp/ats && for i in $(ls *.config); do cat $i > /etc/trafficserver_edit/$i; done; sed -i "s/_AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY_OVERRIDE_/$AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY/g" /etc/trafficserver_edit/*.config']
```

File `/etc/trafficserver_edit/s3_auth_v4.config` looks like:

```
access_key=_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_OVERRIDE_
secret_key=_AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY_OVERRIDE_
version=4
v4-region-map=region_map.config
```

Unfortunately first sed command is zeroing second value in the source file leaving it blank:

```
access_key=AKIA....
secret_key=
version=4
v4-region-map=region_map.config
```

How sed command should look like to prevent that?

edit:
All failing attempts:

```
command: ['sh', '-c', 'cd /tmp/ats && for i in $(ls *.config); do cat $i > /etc/trafficserver_edit/$i; done; sed -e "s/_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_OVERRIDE_/$AWS_ACCESS_KEY/g" ; sed -e "s/_AWS_SECRET_KEY_OVERRIDE_/$AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY/g" /etc/trafficserver_edit/*.config']

command: ['sh', '-c', 'cd /tmp/ats && for i in $(ls *.config); do cat $i > /etc/trafficserver_edit/$i; done; sed -i "s/_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_OVERRIDE_/$AWS_ACCESS_KEY/g" /etc/trafficserver_edit/*.config', 'cd /tmp/ats && for i in $(ls *.config); do cat $i > /etc/trafficserver_edit/$i; done; sed -i "s/_AWS_SECRET_KEY_OVERRIDE_/$AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY/g" /etc/trafficserver_edit/*.config']

command: ['sh', '-c', 'cd /tmp/ats && for i in $(ls *.config); do cat $i > /etc/trafficserver_edit/$i; done; sed -i "s/_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_OVERRIDE_/$AWS_ACCESS_KEY/g;s/_AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY_OVERRIDE_/$AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY/g" /etc/trafficserver_edit/*.config
```

more..

Comment: Are you sure? I see a different outcome: the first key remains unreplaced, the second one gets replaced. That's because the `cat` overwrites the results of the first sed. Why not run both the substitutions in one sed command? `sed -e "s..." -e "s..."`

Comment: @choroba No, that will not work in initContainer command: `sed: bad option in substitution expression`

Comment: So just use two seds with no cat loop in between?

Comment: @choroba Then sed can't see the `/etc/trafficserver_edit/` content.

Comment: Can you use one sed with `sed -e "s///g ; s///g"`?

Comment: @choroba No, that gives me `sed: bad option in substitution expression`

Comment: Wait, by "two seds" I meant `sed -e "..." ; sed -e "..."` in one single-quoted command. They should both see the same content.

Comment: @choroba Same error: `sed: bad option in substitution expression`

Comment: Can you post all the failing variants to the question?

Comment: Also, are you sure the variables don't contain `/` or some other characters special to sed?

Comment: @choroba `AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY` has `/`

Comment: To totally derail this, there is a tool for this https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html

Comment: @SynRomana You can't use `sed` with unsanitized values.

Comment: @SynRomana did you manage to find the solution based on the comments?

Comment: @KFC_ I did: `envsubst`

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer then? This way others who encounter same issue might benefit from it.

Comment: @KFC_ I have added more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I used envsubst to solve this issue. So in my container I am running a Bash script on start doing:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp -ar /etc/trafficserver_init/*.config /etc/trafficserver/
envsubst '$AWS_ACCESS_KEY,$AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY' < /tmp/trafficserver_conf/s3_auth_v4.config > /etc/trafficserver/s3_auth_v4.config
envsubst '$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION' < /tmp/trafficserver_conf/region_map.config > /etc/trafficserver/region_map.config
rm -rf /tmp/trafficserver_conf
```

I have also modified initContainer command to:

```
command: ['sh', '-c', 'cd /tmp/ats && for i in $(ls *.config); do cat $i > /etc/trafficserver_init/$i; done']
```